# Get Date Difference

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to get the difference between two date in my query. I tried using multiple select statement but it's not working

Here's my code

```
$tbl_name = "myTable";
$setDay = "10";

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * (
              SELECT due_date,
                     date_paid,
                     DATEDIFF(due_date, date_paid) as date_interval) 
              FROM $tbl_name 
              WHERE DATEDIFF(due_date, date_paid) <= $setDay 
              ORDER BY trans_id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");
$stmt->execute();
```

Thanks

Comment: This line:  WHERE DATEDIFF(due_date, date_paid) <= $setDay   is causing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to develop you MySQL queries and perfect them outside the context of PHP code first, then integrate the query once you have it working the way you need it to *in a MySQL client application* like MySQL Workbench, PHPMyAdmin, etc.

In your query, the outer `SELECT` is not needed, and the inner query itself looks almost correct, but it is the way you attempt to execute it with PDO that is faulty.

```
SELECT
  due_date,
  date_paid,
  DATEDIFF(due_date, date_paid) as date_interval
FROM $tbl_name
WHERE
  DATEDIFF(due_date, date_paid) <= $setDay
ORDER BY trans_id DESC
LIMIT $start, $limit
```

Now to execute it in PDO, you should be using [`prepare()/bindParam()/execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) to create a prepared statement, bind in parameters, and execute it with those parameters (you cannot bind the table name though - that must remain a variable).  In your current code, you have a mixup of the the `PDO::query()` method used for simple static queries and the `PDOStatement::execute()` method which is used to execute a prepared statement.  You should be using the prepared statement method, rather than `query()`.

```
// Setup the statement with named parameters like :setDay
$sql = "
    SELECT
      due_date,
      date_paid,
      DATEDIFF(due_date, date_paid) as date_interval
    FROM $tbl_name
    WHERE
      DATEDIFF(due_date, date_paid) <= :setDay
    ORDER BY trans_id DESC
    LIMIT :start, :limit
";
// Make PDO throw useful errors on failure
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Prepare the statement
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

// Bind your 3 parameters and execute it
$stmt->bindParam(':setDay', $setDay, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

// Fetch your rows returned from the query
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// Do something with them
print_r($rows);
```

I always recommend spending time with [this PDO tutorial for MySQL developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Running_Statements_With_Parameters) which places PDO's usage in context of the old `mysql_*()` API you may already be familiar with.

Comment: Thanks. But I also need the outer select to display other fields in the table that is why i added it. How do i achieve this cos the result is still same as old. Thanks

Comment: You don't need the outer select - you just add additional fields to the `SELECT` list. You're only dealing with one table and no aggregation, so there's no need for a subquery.

Comment: You will need to clarify your question if you need additional info this does not meet. The `WHERE` condition you indicate an error on is _not_ faulty unless you use that subquery with a closing `)` in the wrong place. As it is now, you can add as many additional fields as needed to the `SELECT`.

Comment: @Chidi See [this example...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c27e/4) and if your situation is more complicate, please edit your question to include sample rows from your table along with a sample of what you would expect your query output to be from those rows.

Comment: You were right even the first time. I wonder with me for the second post but on the road, will give it a short when I'm back. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT * , (select (DATEDIFF(due_date,date_paid)) AS date_interval) FROM $tbl_name
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this to find the date defference,

```
      $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
```

Comment: The OP needs to calculate the difference inside the query, for use in a WHERE condition, not outside in PHP.