# Datediff from 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I am trying to get the days between 2 dates, but I am only getting errors. I tried searching it but non of the things really helped me, I am hoping you guys can help a boy out right here.

The error I get with this code:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native
>   function 'DATEDIFF' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Rent-a-Car\pages\medewerkers.php:197 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Rent-a-Car\pages\medewerkers.php(197):
>   PDO->query('SELECT DATEDIFF...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Rent-a-Car\pages\medewerkers.php on line 197

[my code to display it several times in the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RIY4.png)

[The database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KqHz.png)

The sql command that is used:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM factuur 
LEFT JOIN factuurregel ON factuur.Factuurnummer = factuurregel.Factuurnummer
LEFT JOIN gebruiker ON factuur.Klantcode = gebruiker.Klantcode
LEFT JOIN auto ON factuur.Kenteken = auto.Kenteken";
$sql2 = "SELECT DATEDIFF (day, Begindatum, Einddatum) AS Tijd from factuurregel;";
```

Comment: Your error is pretty clear: You have an incorrect number of parameters inside of the DATEDIFF function. Read this for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087748/get-date-difference

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.  (3) Limit your question to a single query that generates the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250555/incorrect-parameter-count-in-the-call-to-native-function-datediff)

Answer (score 1):

`DATADIFF` function returns a number of days between two dates. You shouldn't pass `day` parameter in it

```
SELECT DATEDIFF (Begindatum, Einddatum) AS Tijd FROM factuurregel
```

Comment: This will still give me this error:  

object(PDOStatement)#5 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(66) "SELECT DATEDIFF (Begindatum, Einddatum) AS Tijd from factuurregel;" }

Comment: object(PDOStatement)#5 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(66) "SELECT DATEDIFF (Begindatum, Einddatum) AS Tijd from factuurregel;" }

Comment: Can you help me? @maximfedorov

Comment: That doesn't look like an error. It looks like a var_dump

Comment: but it isnt the output I need? @apokryfos

Comment: Still, the error for which you raised the question was answered so you would need to update your question with any new issues that have come up along with all necessary information required to reproduce those new issues.

Comment: @thisishowithastobedone Look in the image you posted with the html table, it has a var_dump call, remove it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RIY4.png

Comment: @MatthewPage if i remove it it wil not show me anything and if i echo it it will keep giving me this message

Comment: @thisishowithastobedone yeh this is now a different question completely. maybe start a new one about how to get the values out of the sql result? Your datediff issue is fixed?

Answer (score 1):

the error says that count of parameters is invalid. according to the docs - https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-datediff-function.php:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF (Begindatum, Einddatum) AS Tijd from factuurregel
```

Comment: This will still give me this error: object(PDOStatement)#5 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(66) "SELECT DATEDIFF (Begindatum, Einddatum) AS Tijd from factuurregel;" }

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, then presumably you want:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(Einddatum, Begindatum) AS Tijd
FROM factuurregel;
```

Note that the arguments are reversed.  Both MySQL and SQL Server have functions called `datediff()`.  They differ not only in the number of arguments but also in the order of the dates.